# Excel Function printout select range if not empty (not printing)

Tags: excel, vba, function

Hello I am very new to VBA so please excuse my ignorance.  I am trying to have a function that if the cell is not empty it will print(to the printer) the selected range.  It will not print to the printer but does return my message box and string. I am missing something here?

- Cell a1 = '88888'
- Cell b1 = PrintSelectedArea1(A1) *; returns "Label Printed" and the msgbox but does not print the selection.*
- Cell a2 = isempty
- cell b2=  PrintSelectedArea1(A2) *; *returns "Not Printed"**

I added this code in a new module:

```
Public Function PrintSelectedArea1(r As Range) As String
    If Not IsEmpty(r.Value) Then
    Worksheets("Label").Range("A1:F13").PrintOut
    PrintSelectedArea1 = "Label Printed"
    MsgBox ("Printed")
    Else
    PrintSelectedArea1 = "Not Printed"
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: How do you call your function?

Comment: Note that it is not possible to use `.PrintOut` in a user defined function (UDF) that is used as a formula in a cell. This is not supported by Excel! UDFs cannot manipulate other cells nor can they throw Message boxes nor can they print. The only thing a UDF can do is taking parameters as input and return a value to the cell that called it.

Answer (score 0):

To perform actions you need to use a `Sub` .
you can pass arguments to a Sub, but it does not have a return value.

```
Sub PrintSelectedArea1()
    Worksheets("Label").Range("A1:F13").PrintOut
End Sub
```

The following will look for a change in value in cell B2
If B2 changes to the value 1,`PrintSelectedArea()` will be called. Insert this code in the worksheet you're using.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("B2")) Is Nothing Then
        If Sheets("Label").Range("B2").Value = 1 Then
            Call PrintSelectedArea()
        Else
            MsgBox ("Not printed")
        End If
    End If
    

End Sub
```

Comment: Isn't that line of code the exact same one the OP is already using?

Comment: @braX  Yes, but in a Sub it works, in a Function it does not.

Comment: OK, maybe you can also explain why in your answer?

Comment: Can i call a sub as a cell formula?  I want to print the selection if the cell i am referring to (example PrintSelectedArea1(A2)) is not empty.

Comment: @aconti74 I edited my answer to show how the function can be called as a result of value change to a cell. Thankfully it is not possible to do this via user defined function in a cell, if you could do that it would have printed every time the function was refreshed.